# Can even-dimensional complex skew-symmetric matrices be made block diagonal by orthogonal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, block-matrices

Suppose an even dimensional matrix Q is complex and skew-symmetric. Can Q be written as $Q= O^T \Sigma O$, where O is orthogonal (i.e. $O^T O = O O^T=1$) and $\Sigma$ is block diagonal with $2 \times 2$ blocks?

Comment: what happens in 2 by 2 and 3 by 3 cases?

Comment: What is the context of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such a $\Sigma$, the size of every Jordan block of $Q=O^\top \Sigma O=O^{-1}\Sigma O$ must also be at most $2\times2$. However, according to Lemma 5.2.1 on p.35 of [Olga Ruff's Master thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.146.5519&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=V5iwUbLpMKjqiAfUz4GIBw&usg=AFQjCNHqEzlqYg0TeKHm8T5dADzT_rk9aQ&sig2=8c9JE1WpQghj3i-D3w_WRg&bvm=bv.47534661,d.aGc), for any natural number $k$ and any $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, the matrix $J_k(\lambda)\oplus J_k(-\lambda)$ is similar to some complex skew-symmetric matrix. Hence there exists a complex skew-symmetric matrix $Q$ whose Jordan form contains a $3\times3$ Jordan block. In other words, the answer to your question is negative when the dimension of $Q$ is at least $6\times6$.

Comment: Just a clarification - does your answer apply to even dimensional matrices as well?